# WP_QUERY post_name__not_in

Tags: wordpress

I solved this myself.

```
add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {
  $post_object_id = $args['where']['uriNotIn'];

  $ID = url_to_postid($post_object_id);

  if (isset($post_object_id) && !empty($post_object_id)) {
    $query_args['post__not_in'] = [$ID];
  }

  return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);
```

---

I need all posts that don't have the slug 'common'.

I need the inverse of this (it gives me only common): `$query_args['post_name__in'] = array( 'common' );`.

I've also tried stuff like this (it comes back with empty results):

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
  array(
    'key'     => 'name',
    'value'   => 'common'
    'compare' => '!='
  ),
);
```

Do I need to query the post by the id and then use `post__not_in`? This feels like extra work while I should already have at my disposal in the query loop all that I need.

Full code snippet that I am using:

```
/**
 * Add a 'where' field to query args on the content type
 */
add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {
  $postTypes = array(
    'EarlyChildhoodCentre',
  );

  foreach ($postTypes as $postType) {
    register_graphql_field('RootQueryTo' . $postType . 'ConnectionWhereArgs', 'common', [
      'type' => bool,
      'description' => __('The page is not the default pages and its children, which are to be put on all top level page menus', 'crcs-theme'),
    ]);
  }
});

/**
 * Apply a filter to the created 'where' arg on the content type
 */
add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {
  $post_object_id = $args['where']['common'];

  if (isset($post_object_id)) {
    if ($post_object_id === true) {
      $query_args['name'] = 'common';
    }

    if ($post_object_id === false) {
      // $query_args['name'] = 'common';
      
      // $query_args['post_name__in'] = array( 'common' );

      $query_args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'name',
          'value'   => 'common',
          'compare' => '!='
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);
```

The best I can get is inclusion, which I need but I also need an exclusion, which I cannot work out.

Comment: I solved it myself.